# Cannot install thin on windows

Tags: ruby, thin

I cannot install thin gem on windows. Something happen during build of native extensions.

Do anybody face same issues?

Here is the stack trace:

```
>gem install thin --no-ri --no-rdoc
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing thin:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... no
checking for rb_thread_check_ints()... yes
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for windows.h... yes
checking for winsock.h... yes
checking for main() in -lkernel32... yes
checking for main() in -lrpcrt4... yes
checking for main() in -lgdi32... yes
checking for main() in -lssl... no
creating Makefile

make
g++ -I. -IC:/Ruby/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -I/C/Ruby/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/C/Ru
by/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DBUILD_FOR_RUBY -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_TBR -DHAVE_RB_THR
EAD_CHECK_INTS -DHAVE_RB_TIME_NEW -DOS_WIN32 -DHAVE_WINDOWS_H -DHAVE_WINSOCK_H -DWITHOUT_SSL -DHAVE_
MAKE_PAIR    -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -
Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o binder.o -c binder.cpp
In file included from project.h:137:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
binder.h:35:34: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:138:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
em.h:91:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:92:76: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:93:56: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:95:57: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:96:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:97:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:98:55: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:99:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:101:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:106:42: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:123:45: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:132:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:45:61: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:46:112: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:47:69: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:49:73: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:62:75: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:63:74: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:64:77: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:65:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:99:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:100:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:102:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:105:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
g++ -I. -IC:/Ruby/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -I/C/Ruby/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/C/Ru
by/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DBUILD_FOR_RUBY -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_TBR -DHAVE_RB_THR
EAD_CHECK_INTS -DHAVE_RB_TIME_NEW -DOS_WIN32 -DHAVE_WINDOWS_H -DHAVE_WINSOCK_H -DWITHOUT_SSL -DHAVE_
MAKE_PAIR    -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -
Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long   -o cmain.o -c cmain.cpp
In file included from project.h:137:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
binder.h:35:34: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:138:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
em.h:91:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:92:76: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:93:56: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:95:57: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:96:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:97:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:98:55: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:99:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:101:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:106:42: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:123:45: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:132:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:45:61: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:46:112: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:47:69: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:49:73: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:62:75: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:63:74: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:64:77: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:65:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:99:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:100:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:102:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:105:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:98:71: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:109:122: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:119:79: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:129:83: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:260:85: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:270:84: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:280:88: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:290:51: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:300:70: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:320:55: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:546:70: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:669:68: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp: In function 'int evma_send_file_data_to_connection(long unsigned int, const char*)':
cmain.cpp:752:6: error: cannot convert 'stat*' to '_stati64*' for argument '2' to 'int _fstati64(int
, _stati64*)'
make: *** [cmain.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10 for inspect
ion.
Results logged to C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/ext/gem_make.out
```

Comment: I'm having this same problem! I did the steps and when i do `thin start` i get an error `No adapter found for C:/Ruby192/bin`. Help?

Comment: I am having the same problem too

Comment: please check this https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/251

Comment: devkit is required before thin and eventmachine if you are running on windows https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/development-kit

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Installing from the git or rubygems repositories no longer works (currently) under 1.9.2 or 1.9.3 (confirmed still broken on 2012-June-22). Instead, you need to simply:

```
gem install eventmachine --pre
gem install thin
```

Note that on 2012-June-18 the current prerelease was [renamed to `1.0.0.rc.1`](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/commit/5c66eeabc37d727873da22690734c41e82339334), so there is a possibility that 'soon' the version that works with Windows will become the official release and this will no longer be a problem.

---

*If you try to build the gem under 1.9.2 from the github repo you may see this (included for search engine hits):*

```
C:\eventmachine> rake build
(in C:/eventmachine)
cd ext
C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.
```

*If you try to install the gem under 1.9.3 from the rubygems repo you may see this (included for search engine hits):*

```
C:\>gem install eventmachine
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for inotify_init() in sys/inotify.h... no
checking for __NR_inotify_init in sys/syscall.h... no
checking for writev() in sys/uio.h... no
checking for rb_thread_check_ints()... yes
checking for rb_time_new()... yes
checking for windows.h... yes
checking for winsock.h... yes
checking for main() in -lkernel32... yes
checking for main() in -lrpcrt4... yes
checking for main() in -lgdi32... yes
checking for main() in -lssl... no
creating Makefile

make
generating rubyeventmachine-i386-mingw32.def
compiling binder.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from binder.cpp:20:0:
project.h:85:0: warning: "FD_SETSIZE" redefined
:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from project.h:137:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
binder.h:35:34: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:138:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
em.h:91:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:92:76: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:93:56: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:95:57: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:96:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:97:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:98:55: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:99:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:101:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:106:42: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:123:45: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:132:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:45:61: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:46:112: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:47:69: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:49:73: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:62:75: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:63:74: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:64:77: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:65:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from binder.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:99:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:100:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:102:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:105:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
compiling cmain.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wdeclaration-after-statement" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
cc1plus.exe: warning: command line option "-Wimplicit-function-declaration" is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from cmain.cpp:20:0:
project.h:85:0: warning: "FD_SETSIZE" redefined
:0:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from project.h:137:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
binder.h:35:34: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:138:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
em.h:91:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:92:76: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:93:56: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:95:57: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:96:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:97:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:98:55: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:99:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:101:47: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:106:42: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:123:45: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
em.h:132:36: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:45:61: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:46:112: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:47:69: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:49:73: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:62:75: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:63:74: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:64:77: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:65:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
In file included from project.h:145:0,
                 from cmain.cpp:20:
eventmachine.h:99:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:100:58: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:102:60: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
eventmachine.h:105:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:98:71: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:109:122: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:119:79: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:129:83: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:260:85: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:270:84: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:280:88: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:290:51: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:300:70: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:320:55: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:546:70: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp:669:68: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type
cmain.cpp: In function 'int evma_send_file_data_to_connection(long unsigned int, const char*)':
cmain.cpp:752:6: error: cannot convert 'stat*' to '_stati64*' for argument '2' to 'int _fstati64(int, _stati64*)'
make: *** [cmain.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/ext/gem_make.out
```

Comment: The only solution that worked for me . However the actual command for installing eventmachine that worked is: gem install eventmachine -v 1.0.0.beta.2 --pre

Comment: Had an `cannot convert 'stat*' to '_stati64*'` error during eventmachine installation and `gem install eventmachine --pre` solved my problem too. Many thanks

Comment: Quick note to say this fixed the problem for me. As I wanted to fix this for all my machines, and I'm coding a rails app, I added the following in my Gemfile: `gem 'eventmachine', '1.0.0.beta.4.1', :platforms => [:mswin, :mingw]` - I got the version by doing the installation above, and copying that version number over. I double-checked this with `gem list -r --pre eventmachine`

Comment: gem install eventmachine --pre solved my problem of installing caldecott. Thanks.

Comment: Also note that the version of devkit must be compatible with the version of ruby. See devkit wiki https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit#requirements

Answer (score 6):

First, install the DevKit from the RubyInstaller for Windows [website](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) (which it appears you have already done).

Then install eventmachine separately from the git repository as Roger shows.

```
> gem install specific_install
Successfully installed backports-1.18.1
Successfully installed specific_install-0.2.3
2 gems installed
...
> gem specific_install -l http://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine.git
git installing from http://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine.git
...
Successfully built RubyGem
Name: eventmachine
Version: 0.12.11
File: eventmachine-0.12.11.gem
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed eventmachine-0.12.11
1 gem installed
...
successfully installed
```

You should then be able to install thin from the gem.

```
> gem install thin
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Successfully installed thin-1.2.7-x86-mingw32
1 gem installed 
...
> thin start
Using rack adapter
Thin web server (v1.2.7 codename No Hup)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

Comment: gem specific_install -l http://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine.git - should be called from git bush. It won't work in windows console.

Answer (score 3):

Try the running the following

```
gem install thin –ignore-dependencies
```

If it fails retry installing rack and eventmachine and then re-running the above command.

```
gem install rack
gem install eventmachine -l
gem install thin –ignore-dependencies
```

Answer (score 3):

This will help you...

Add this below line to your gem file

**gem 'eventmachine', :git => 'https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine.git'**

then run **bundle install**

Comment: Worked for me with Win 7 x64 and Ruby 2.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
$ gem install specific_install
$ gem specific_install -l http://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine.git
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install Thin without needing to build it yourself by using the pre-built binaries but you need to know which ones.  To get the latest pre-built win32 version do the following:

1. Go to the [RubyGems Thin page](http://rubygems.org/gems/thin)
2. Look under the "Versions" section for a version that has "x86-mswin32" to the right of it.  (As of today versions 1.2.11, 1.2.10, etc all have win32 binaries)
3. Run the following following "gem install" command with the version of Thin included with the "-v" flag:

> gem install thin -v 1.2.11

Here are the results from my installation:

```
c:\>gem install thin -v 1.2.11
Successfully installed thin-1.2.11-x86-mswin32
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for thin-1.2.11-x86-mswin32... 
Updating ri class cache with 3611 classes... 
Installing RDoc documentation for thin-1.2.11-x86-mswin32...
```