# WEBrick alterative for Rails 2.3.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, webrick, thin

I'm a Rails newbie, and I was initially using NetBeans + JRuby to make Rails apps (was using JRuby because it was a quick start - I don't need to interface with any Java libs).

Then because of *(a)* many gems are not available for JRuby, and *(b)* most of the Rails webshosts don't support JRuby, I decided to use Ruby MRI.

So I got everything installed and it was working OK. But now, after every 4/5 refreshes of a webpage, WEBrick crashes with a [SEGFAULT](http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/3784). (Nothing like this happened when I was using JRuby).

So, I went about looking for an alternative, and tried thin. Some errors which [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649252/cannot-install-thin-on-windows) helped partly resolve. Now on `thin start` I get an error `No adapter found for C:/Ruby192/bin`.

Any advice on how to get started developing again with (any) simple (stable) web server is highly appreciated.

**Ps.** *I'm using Windows 7 x64, if that helps.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going with thin under Ruby 1.8.7p0

Answer (score 1):

Use Passenger lite.

```
$ gem install passenger
$ cd /path/to/rails
$ passenger start
```

The first time you run start, it will download, compile and install the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try mongrel for development. But I suggest to go the passenger way in production. The alternative would be a mongrel cluster. Just install the mongrel gem, Rails will automatically use that then when firing up the server.

Comment: I didn't try that yet, because it seems mongrel doesn't work with Rails 2.3.8: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4690-mongrel-doesnt-work-with-rails-238