# Recommended development web server for Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, linux, ruby-on-rails-3

What web server would you recommend for [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) 3 web development on Linux? How about Windows?

Comment: what's the problem with already packaged WEBrick? Or may be Mongrel as developmet web server (I meant one that require during development). Or do you want to know a good Production server for Rails3?

Comment: I know at least 3 development web servers: Mongrel, WEBrick, Unicorn. I just want to know which one is better for web development with rail3.

Comment: I had major problems with WEBrick on Windows (segfaults after every 2/3 requests). thin saved the day for me!

Comment: For Windows I'm currently running thin under IIS 6.  Here's a link to my blog post about it: http://transfermodeawesome.posterous.com/2011/06/installing-spree-on-windows-2003-server.html.  It's a tad out of date but the ideas are still valid and there are a few choice tidbits on getting gems working on Windows.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'd recommend the [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) server. Works great both on Linux and Windows. And it's very easy to install: `gem install thin`. If you are using Rails 3, you may want to add it do your Gemfile instead:

```
group :development do
  gem "thin"
end
```

And then run `bundle install`.

Once it's installed, you can run it with: `rails s thin`.

I find it a very fast and clean choice.

Just a note: thin depends on the eventmachine gem. I had a hard time making it work on Windows. You might want to link it to this specific ref in github to avoid trouble:

```
gem "eventmachine", :git => "http://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine.git", :ref => "6c7997798"
```

As far as I remember, the last version of eventmachine does not build on Windows.

Comment: Or check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4200880/292008.  eventmachine works fine, just do `gem install eventmachine --pre`

Comment: Oh, and the best thing about using `thin` on windows: ctrl-c works!

Answer (score 8):

In Rails 3, you can use [Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/) with ease!

```
group :development do
  gem "unicorn"
end
```

Instead of `rails s` you start your server by simply running

```
unicorn
```

For more verbose output, use

```
unicorn -d
```

Answer (score 4):

Passenger 3 Standalone.
As easy as `passenger start`.

On Windows the best is a VirtualBox instance running the same setup.

Answer (score 0):

you might also consider using [Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/) as your web server for rails 3. For Windows, you can run mongrel cluster with apache or nginx.