# Debugging Rails Server with RubyMine 5: Which server?

Tags: rubymine

Any recommendations for which server is the best to use for RubyMine debugging?

- Webrick works correctly, but is slow to start.
- Unicorn starts quickly, but the debugger doesn't work as the session quickly times out. better_errors gem doesn't play well with unicorn.

Any others to try?

UPDATE

- Thin seems to work great

Comment: See the [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535220/recommended-development-web-server-for-ruby-on-rails-3). AFAIK, Unicorn is not compatible with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Full disclaimer, I installed rubymine today, and know very little about it... *BUT,* I did just read this about rubymine, unicorn, and timeouts which may help: [Run/Debug Configuration: Rails](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-rails.html)

tl;dr:

```
if ENV['IDE_PROCESS_DISPATCHER']
    timeout 30 * 60 * 60 * 24
end
```