# Installing thin (1.5.0) with native extensions "...ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension."

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, thin

I have a new project need to use thin but there is something wrong. 
In my Gemfile.

```
gem 'thin'
```

And then I run "bundle install". It shows:

```
......
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for main() in -lc... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
    --with-thin_parser-dir
    --without-thin_parser-dir
    --with-thin_parser-include
    --without-thin_parser-include=${thin_parser-dir}/include
    --with-thin_parser-lib
    --without-thin_parser-lib=${thin_parser-dir}/lib
    --with-clib
    --without-clib
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:461:in `try_link0'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:476:in `try_link'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:619:in `try_func'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:845:in `block in have_library'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:840:in `have_library'
    from extconf.rb:4:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/ext/thin_parser/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing thin (1.5.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install thin -v '1.5.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Please help me to solve this problem. I once installed thin before, but I don't know why fail this time.

Comment: see this link for your solution

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649252/cannot-install-thin-on-windows/4200880#4200880

Comment: I tried this way before. It didn't work.

Comment: I found my problem. I updated Xcode, and I have to reinstall command line tools.

Answer (score 0):

gem install thin
or
gem install thin -v '1.5.0'