# Installing Thin on Windows fails

Tags: ruby, rubygems, thin

I cannot seem to install the thin gem on windows.
A very similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649252/cannot-install-thin-on-windows), however after tying all the answers it still doesn't work.

Trace:

```
C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lc... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby
    --with-thin_parser-dir
    --without-thin_parser-dir
    --with-thin_parser-include
    --without-thin_parser-include=${thin_parser-dir}/include
    --with-thin_parser-lib
    --without-thin_parser-lib=${thin_parser-dir}/lib
    --with-clib
    --without-clib
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:461:in `try_link0'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:476:in `try_link'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:619:in `try_func'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:845:in `block in have_library'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:840:in `have_library'
    from extconf.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

DevKit from the RubyInstaller for Windows has been installed.
Timemachine has been installed.

Other gems work just fine.
Does anybody face the same or similar issues?
Using Windows 7 Professional and latest 1.9 Ruby.

BTW:
I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208965/installing-thin-1-5-0-with-native-extensions-error-failed-to-build-gem-na) question. The comments refer  back to the above mentioned question and a possible solution is to reinstall Xcode. But I am not using Xcode, nor have it installed.

Comment: Xcode is a OSX thing, not for Win. Your problem is: it somehow couldn't find DevKit installation. So you need to carefully find why it is.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I understand Xcode is for OSX. DevKit is installed and seems to be configured properly; the config file includes the paths to the gems.

Answer (score 0):

I just had errors installing thin, and the initial one's look like yours.

The problem is that the devkitvars.bat isn't being run.  If you run this first, then do a gem install thin..

```
C:\<PATHTODEVKIT>\devkitvars.bat
```

Depending on your setup you'll progress.

The problem was for me that my initial install of both ruby and devkit were in a directory with spaces.  Sometimes I don't feel like computer science has progressed..

So I moved the directories, changed the environment path variable, and the registry variables for ruby, and verified the ruby install.

Then I:

```
del <devkitdir>\config.yml
ruby dk.rb init
ruby dk.rb install

gem install thin
```

I got your error.

Which is where the long term solution comes.

In the [RubyDir]\lib\ruby\site-ruby directory, there is a file called devkit.rb that wasn't changed.

Perhaps if I had deleted this file, the dk.rb install would generate it (assuming they are using make to move this file here, and aren't checking registry entries or anything).  But I edited it, and changed the path of the devkit location to the new location.

That ends your error.  I also got the errors associated with the page you reference.  I followed one of those solutions:

```
$ gem install specific_install
$ gem specific_install -l http://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine.git

gem install thin
```

Hip Hip!

Hope this helps.